# In Python, multiple processes in a process pool encountered errors while modifying shared variables generated by the Manager module

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, locking, shared-variable

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager

def task(args):
    k, v, sharedDict, lock = args
    with lock:
        if k not in sharedDict:
            sharedDict[k] = {}
            sharedDict[k]['current'] = v
            print(f"sharedDict[k]['current'] = {sharedDict[k]['current']}")

def main():
    manager = Manager()
    lock = manager.Lock()
    dic = manager.dict()
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    tasks = [('a', {'A': 1}, dic, lock), ('b', {'B': 2}, dic, lock), ('c', {'C': 3}, dic, lock), ('d', {'D': 4}, dic, lock)]
    pool.map(task, tasks)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run the code above, this line throws an error:print(f"sharedDict[k]['current'] ={sharedDict[k]['current']}"),KeyError: 'current', even though I've clearly added the value to the dictionary. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: You cannot update nested dict that way. Read [this section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#proxy-objects).

Comment: Can you tell me how to make modifications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Python docs[1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#proxy-objects),

> If standard (non-proxy) list or dict objects are contained in a referent, modifications to those mutable values will not be propagated through the manager because the proxy has no way of knowing when the values contained within are modified. However, storing a value in a container proxy (which triggers a `__setitem__` on the proxy object) does propagate through the manager and so to effectively modify such an item, one could re-assign the modified value to the container proxy

```py
sharedDict[k] = {}
sharedDict[k]['current'] = v
print(f"sharedDict[k]['current'] = {sharedDict[k]['current']}")
```

`sharedDict[k]` is non proxy nested object in in `sharedDict`. Its changes won't be propagated because the proxy has no way of knowing when the values contained within are modified.

The work around is to create a temporary local dict.

```py
def task(args):
    k, v, shared_dict, lock = args
    with lock:
        if k not in shared_dict:
            shared_dict[k] = {}
            inner_dict = shared_dict[k]
            inner_dict['current'] = v
            shared_dict[k] = inner_dict
            pprint(f"{shared_dict[k]['current'] = }")
```

The line `shared_dict[k] = inner_dict` will call the `__setitem__` on the `sharedDict` forcing it to update.

Credit to @ken

Comment: Thank you for your response, it resolved the issue that had been troubling me for two days, and it has been very helpful to me.

Comment: @zhangshuai Feel free to accept one of the answer that worked for you

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, `manager.dict()` is a proxy object, but the assigned `{}` in `sharedDict[k] = {}` is not. It's a regular Python dictionary. Assignments made in the inner dict are not proxied. A future indexing `sharedDict[k]` gets another copy of the original dictionary still held by the proxy which has never seen the local modifications.

Yoshikage Kira shows a great solution - update and reassign the local copy. But you could also create proxy dicts in the worker process. Managers create a process that works as a common server for proxied objects. Your pool workers could connect to the same server and create their own managed dictionaries.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager, managers

def task_init(address):
    global task_manager
    task_manager = managers.SyncManager(address=address)
    task_manager.connect()
    
def task(args):
    k, v, sharedDict, lock = args
    with lock:
        if k not in sharedDict:
            sharedDict[k] = task_manager.dict()
            sharedDict[k]['current'] = v
            print(f"sharedDict[k]['current'] = {sharedDict[k]['current']}")

def main():
    manager = Manager()
    lock = manager.Lock()
    dic = manager.dict()
    pool = Pool(processes=2, initializer=task_init, initargs=[manager.address])
    tasks = [('a', {'A': 1}, dic, lock), ('b', {'B': 2}, dic, lock), ('c', {'C': 3}, dic, lock), ('d', {'D': 4}, dic, lock)]
    pool.map(task, tasks)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Either way, that seems like an awful lot of interprocess proxy calls and copying of data. And you are right! Managers can really suck resources. Wait, did I just imply managers suck? Um... If you can solve your problem without them, you may find you have a faster program.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it resolved the issue that had been troubling me for two days, and it has been very helpful to me.